# Multiple columns with images and wrapped text in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

I need a `frame` looking like the image below in `beamer`. The 3rd column will have multirow text with an equation. There are no horizontal lines, neither do I need the boxes around each of the columns.

[image]

I tried `\subfloat` and `\minipage`. With `\subfloat` the text doesn't show up and with `\minipage` the images are placed one over other and the text is not wrapped.

```
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.46]{images/fig1} 
\end{minipage}
\pause
&
\begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.46]{images/fig2}
\end{minipage}
\pause
&
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\textbf{Title} \newline
                            text1 \newline 
                            text2 \newline
                            text3 \newline
\end{minipage}

\end{tabular}
```

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides the `columns` environment. Within it, you specify a `column` environment with a given width. Together, the following generic structure is used:

```
\begin{columns}[<options>]
  \begin{column}{<width>}
    ...
  \end{column}
  ...
  \begin{column}{<width>}
    ...
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

It is best to specify the above `<width>` parameters as factors of `\textwidth`. As such, I've passed the option `onlytextwidth` to `columns` in the example below. Since these environments are inherent to `beamer`, it doesn't warrant using something like [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol). Here's an example of what you might be after - I used `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` to denote your graphics:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame title}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \rule{100pt}{150pt}% Place your graphic here
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
      \centering
      \rule{40pt}{150pt}% Place your graphic here
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    Here is some regular text in a column. And there is an equation
    \[
      f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
    \]
    Here is some more text.
    \end{column}
​  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

Read the [`beamer` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (p 127, section **12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns**) for more information.

---

For adjusting the vertical alignment of the columns, you can add the `t` (for `t`op) option to the `columns` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{This is a frame title}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,t]
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=40pt,height=150pt,valign=t]{example-image-a}% Place your graphic here
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=40pt,height=150pt,valign=t]{example-image-b}% Place your graphic here
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
    Here is some regular text in a column. And there is an equation
    \[
      f(x)=ax^2+bx+c
    \]
    Here is some more text.
    \end{column}
​  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

Note that the inclusion of graphics makes for some unintuitive output in terms of alignment. That's before alignment at the `t`op implies the "baseline of the `t`op line." And since graphics are placed in a single line, their `t`op turns out to be more like their `b`ottom. To correct for this, we use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=t` option, which is `export` to be used as part of [`graphicsx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` options.

Comment: Is there any way to put the text at top of the column aligned with the pictures? In your example, it is not and I have not achieved it with the options for columns command

Comment: @MarcosAlex: See the updated answer.