# How to remove the warnings "Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available" and "Size substitutions with differences" in beamer?

Tags: fonts, beamer, warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
```

I am using the files from http://www.poirrier.be/~jean-etienne/info/latexbeamer/latex-beamer.tar.gz.

Alternatively, for a minimal working example, the presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces the warnings.

---

How to remove the above 2 warnings?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

to your document preamble.

Fonts are typically available only in certain sizes/increments. As an example, the basic `article` document class loads only the following sizes (from [`size10.clo`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo?view=co)):

- `\tiny` @ `5pt`;
- `\scriptsize` @ `7pt`;
- `\footnotesize` @ `8pt`;
- `\small` @ `9pt`;
- `\normalsize` @ `10pt`;
- `\large` @ `12pt`;
- `\Large` @ `14.4pt`;
- `\LARGE` @ `17.28pt`;
- `\huge` @ `20.74pt`; and
- `\Huge` @ `24.88pt`

So, requesting a `15pt` font size using something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont Hello world.
\end{document}
```

leads to LaTeX complaining in the `.log` file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <15> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 3.
...
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.6pt have occurred.
```

Using [`lmodern`](//ctan.org/pkg/lm) removes this restriction by allowing font sizes at arbitrary sizes. For more on font size requirements, see [Fonts at arbitrary sizes](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-fontsize).

Comment: I know this workaround, but I also know that if you do that, math accents will be typesetted very badly. You can try i.e. `$\ddot u$` or `$\tilde J$`

Comment: I used package `lmodern`and it worked fine until I used `\scshape` and no matter the size I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @VagelisBebelis: *Where* are you using `\scshape`? Perhaps with a **bold** or *italics* font? They don't have small-caps included.

Comment: @Werner I use it with `beamer`. The small-caps show nicely but I get the warning. So, I guess I just need to change font to one that supports small-caps?

Comment: With `svjour` class, `lmodern` still gives an error `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'U/lasy/m/n' in size <13> not available`. `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` suggested by Dotene in another answer was what worked for me.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh: That's because [`lmodern`](//ctan.org/pkg/lm) only replaces the Computer Modern font family, not *all* fonts.

Comment: @Werner Perhaps you could clarify this in the answer.

Comment: The link at the end is broken, here is the new one: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-fontsize

Comment: @Wauzl I can't agree with you more The accepted answer has not solve my problem, however, after I used the package `lmorden`, the number of warnings increased from less than 10 to 1K+...

Answer (score 52):

Add `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` to your preamble.

Comment: This is what worked for me. With `lmodern` suggested in the accepted answer, I stil got the warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'U/lasy/m/n' in size <13> not available`.

Comment: This scales all fonts, which *is* a reasonable fallback; but one should first fix warnings by selecting better fonts (like `lmodern`) where possible.

Comment: Using `anyfontsize` worked for me when using this thesis template https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis. Using `lmodern` did nothing (regardless of whether `anyfontsize` was included or not).

Answer (score 15):

You can add this `\let\Tiny=\tiny` just after the `documentclass` declaration. So, it should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
```

Hope this helps! :)

Links:
[1] http://texblog.net/latex-archive/presentations/beamer-warnings/

Answer (score 2):

Beamer versions 3.44 and newer no longer produce this warning.

It was fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/3bac00a7a4d95067ccb6e6aac0f0be1c9f802a1a

Comment: Nope, installed a new version today (May 20, 2020), and it still has this warning.

Comment: @mathreader Something's fishy. I never had the warning since the update, and I just tested it again (just to be sure).