# How to add url to footer in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, urls

I'm new to LaTeX and am having trouble adding a url to the footer.

I currently have this:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemebars} 

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today}   

\begin{document}
```

So far all of that information appear correctly on each page, but I wanted to make the Institute a link to a url, any ideas?

Comment: You can use `\href{www.myinstitute.com}{Institute}`

Comment: Thanks Marco but I tried that it comes up with the error: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: The command must be used as a argument of `\institute`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 5):

Marcos example:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemebars} 

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{\href{http://www.mit.edu}{Institute}}
\date{\today}   

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Alternative: `\institute{Institute \url{http://www.mit.edu}}`

Comment: Awesome that worked like a charm, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something different with respect to Herbert's answer:

1. in the title page I'd insert both name and link;
2. in the footer I'd insert just the link.

This is perfectly doable thanks to the syntax:

```
\institute[things in footer line]{things in title page}
```

Thus:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern} % used to remove font warnings as per:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/13304
\usepackage{beamerthemebars} 

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX.SX}]{TeX.SX \\ \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
\date{\today}   

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]