# Beamer: show subitem at the same time as the item

Tags: beamer, overlays

In Beamer whenever you have

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\begin{itemize}
\item a1
\item a2
\end{itemize}
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
```

subitem a1 appears after item A.

What if I want that when A appears the first subitem also appear?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To let the first subitem appear, you have to tell it explicitly with:

```
\item<.>
```

or

```
\item<.->
```

which does not increase the overlay specification (the second makes persistent the item).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\begin{itemize}
\item<.-> a1
\item a2
\end{itemize}
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, why is the package `lmodern`? Your approach works for me without it.

Comment: @hengxin: Happy it helps. For your problem with lmodern, that package is not strictly necessary: it helps in [removing the warning “Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/13304)

Comment: can this be made the default behavior with `beamerdefaultoverlayspecification`?

Comment: I just made this question as a separate post in case! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523764/beamer-default-overlay-show-subitem-at-the-same-time-as-the-item Thanks!!