# How to make the \frametitle row smaller in berkeley theme in beamer

Tags: beamer

[image: my problem of berkeley]

This theme is good,but I want the row a little small, how can I edit it. Thanks

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[space,noindent]{ctex}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\begin{document}
\kaishu
\title[aaa]{aaa}
\subtitle{aaa}
\author{aaa}
\institute[aaa]{aaa}
\date[aaa]{aaa}
\logo{\includegraphics{TeXlogo.pdf}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{aaa}
\subsection{aaa}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aaa}
\framesubtitle{aaa}
aaa 1、2、3...
\end{frame}
...

\begin{frame}
aaa...
\end{frame}

...
\section{aaa}
\subsection{aaa}
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the height of the header in your preamble by adjusting `\beamer@headheight` accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
  Some final text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The default is `2.5\baselineskip`, which results in 62.5pt (2.5 x 25pt) under the 14pt base font you selected.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful
And if I want to learn to edit other, just go % http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer. to see the document, Am I right？
Again thank you for help  :-D

Comment: And a error?
\let\Tiny=\tiny

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: You can look at [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)'s [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) to learn more about the general principles of presentation. However, each theme holds its own intricacies and make-up. The quick-fix `\let\Tiny\tiny` is from [How to remove the warnings “Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available” and “Size substitutions with differences” in `beamer`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764). Alternatively, add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to your document preamble.

Comment: Great
By the document, I use "\usetheme[width=50pt]{Berkeley}" to set the sidebar width.

 I set the text's line spacing. I use "\setbeamerfont{sidebar}{size*={8pt}{1pt}}" just in the page 197

Comment: But how can I set the text in frametitle vertically center(not horizontal alignment), Thanks

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: The frame title is vertically centred, so I would say that you *want* it horizontally centred... right?

Comment: No,I think I find reasons, the height include { frame title} and{ framesubtitle}, so without framesubtitle, it looks like the frametitle is in the top.

Can I cancel the framsubtitle height when I don't use it while I want the framsubtitle height when I use it. All the total height in my example will be the same. It will make the frametitle center without the framsubtitle. Can I do this? Sorry to trouble you and thanks! :-D

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: That's not what I see - [see image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DOYq4.png). Without a `\framesubtitle` the `\frametitle` is lowered. It may not be completely in the middle, but that's just because the frame title `Frame title` doesn't have any descenders. See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E97VM.png) that better highlights the vertical alignment of the frame title *without* a frame subtitle.

Comment: Yes,you are right, I get false because I set the frame title height too small, so the middle is not apparent. I make it bigger. It's OK now, Thanks for helping. My question is solved.
The code "\beamer@headheight" and the book in Page145 "\usetheme[headheight=⟨head height⟩,footheight=⟨foot height⟩]{boxes}" is it same? otherwise, I cannot find any include the "headheight". Then if not; then if you'll allow a slight digression, how do you know the code "\beamer@headheight". Thanks

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: According to an investigation into the code of the [outer theme `sidebar`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesidebar.sty), it seems like `height` would be the appropriate key choice (as in `\usetheme[height=<len>]{Berkeley}`. However, it doesn't work. I've [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11754373#11754373) [the `beamer` maintainer in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11757716#11757716), but don't know the solution just yet. Using `\beamer@headheight` as-is works in the interim.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem quickly and efficiently. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing wit beamer's internal lengths, one can simply pass the height option to the sidebar outer theme by using `\PassOptionsToPackage{height=1.5cm}{beamerouterthemesidebar}` before the theme is loaded:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[space,noindent]{ctex}

\PassOptionsToPackage{height=1.5cm}{beamerouterthemesidebar}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\begin{document}
%\kaishu
\title[aaa]{aaa}
\subtitle{aaa}
\author{aaa}
\institute[aaa]{aaa}
\date[aaa]{aaa}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{aaa}
\subsection{aaa}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aaa}
\framesubtitle{aaa}
aaa 123...
\end{frame}
...

\begin{frame}
aaa...
\end{frame}

...
\section{aaa}
\subsection{aaa}
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```