# Rochester theme titlepage change height of top bar

Tags: beamer, titles, height

I want to change the height of the top bar but only on the titlepage. I want to set it first to 7mm, then to 14mm. How can I do that? Now I only know that I can change the height by `\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}`.

Comment: Related: [How to make the `\frametitle` row smaller in `Berkeley` theme in `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139447/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Rochester` theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeRochester.sty) uses the [`sidebar` outer theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesidebar.sty). So, we set the default height to `14mm` and then temporarily change (using a group) it to `7mm` and redefine the `headline` template for the `sidebar theme`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\usetheme[height=14mm]{Rochester}
\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it

% Temporarily adjust header height to 7mm, only for title page
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=7mm
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@headline@sidebar theme\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sidebar theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vspace*{\beamer@headheight}
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup
% Header height restored to 14mm

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer! Best regards, Krzysiek

Comment: @Krzysiek: If this answered your question, consider upvoting and accepting. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Comment: @Krzysiek: You should ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk). Although I don't know the extent of such a solution, it may be too much to include in a comment (...said Fermat `:)` ).