# Modify distance between title box and top bar on title frame

Tags: beamer, titles

This is a follow-up question to [Rochester theme titlepage change height of top bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140354/rochester-theme-titlepage-change-height-of-top-bar)

I try to modify the distance between the title box and the top bar. Right now I only managed to change the height of the top bar.

Do you have any idea how to do that? Or maybe simply remove the top bar from the title page and move the title bar to the top?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\usetheme[height=14mm]{Rochester}
\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it

% Temporarily adjust header height to 7mm, only for title page
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=7mm
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@headline@sidebar theme\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sidebar theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vspace*{\beamer@headheight}
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup
% Header height restored to 14mm

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title page sets the title content vertically centred using a

```
\vfill
% <title content>
\vfill
```

approach. You can replace the first `\vfill` with a fixed `\vspace`. This replacement can be performed using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd` on the `title page` beamer template (stored in `\beamer@@tmpl@title page`). Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname beamer@@tmpl@title page\endcsname% <cmd>
  {\vfill}% <search>
  {\vspace*{<len>}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

You need to specify an appropriate value for `<len>` above. Here is the difference between the default (without the patch) and if you use `-15mm`:

[image]