# Beamer table centering in Rochester?

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment

I try to *center* the table in beamer but even if I use `\begin{center}` there is still more space on the left than on the right. Have you any idea what I can do with that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Rochester}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
\begin{small}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm} c c c c}
    \toprule
    \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty}\\
    \midrule
    {qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwe} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwe} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudnione} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwe}\\
\midrule
    \pause
    {qwerty} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa}\\
\midrule
\pause
{qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Trudny} & \textcolor{red}{Trudny} & \textcolor{green}{Prosty} & \textcolor{green}{Prosty}\\
\midrule
\pause
{qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwa} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwa} &    \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa}\\
    \bottomrule
    \pause
       \end{tabular}
   \end{small}

   \textbf{qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty    qwerty    qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty }
   \end{center}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be, that due to your fixed column width `p{3cm}` the table is wider than the `textwidth`. That's why it goes into the margin on the right side.

With only `c` instead of `p{3cm}` it seems centred:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{esint}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{Rochester}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{small}
                \begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
                    \toprule
                    \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty} & \textbf{qwerty}\\
                    \midrule
                    {qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwe} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwe} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudnione} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwe}\\                      \midrule
                    \pause
                    {qwerty} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa}\\                      \midrule
                    \pause
                    {qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Trudny} & \textcolor{red}{Trudny} & \textcolor{green}{Prosty} & \textcolor{green}{Prosty}\\                       \midrule
                    \pause
                    {qwerty} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwa} & \textcolor{red}{Niemożliwa} &    \textcolor{orange}{Utrudniona} & \textcolor{green}{Możliwa}\\                      \bottomrule
                    \pause
                \end{tabular}
            \end{small}

            \textbf{qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty    qwerty    qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty }
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your tabular is centered but to big:

> Overfull \hbox (13.76324pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 42--42

This is about 0.5 inch and this difference you can see.