# Same color and size of tableofcontents? (Beamer, Warsaw)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

I want to write something with the exact same color and size that the title sections are written in the Warsaw theme of Beamer, but in a random place of the presentation as any other word. Is that possible? And it is possible to put the ball marker to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following minimal example defines `\toclikesection[<number>]{<title>}` which prints a ToC-like entry for a section entitled `<title>` with a possible number `<number>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newcommand{\toclikesection}[2][]{%
  \def\inserttocsectionnumber{#1}% Number
  \def\inserttocsection{#2}% Title
  \usebeamertemplate**{section in toc}% Print section-like entry
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\begin{frame}
First frame

\toclikesection{A fake section}

\toclikesection[3]{Another fake section}

\toclikesection[a]{Lettered fake section}
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\begin{frame}
Second frame
\end{frame}

\section{Final section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
First subsection frame
\end{frame}

\subsection{Final subsection}
\begin{frame}
Last subsection frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```