# How to make the text of list horizontally in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

The MWE is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}

     \begin{center}
       \begin{enumerate}
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \begin{itemize}
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \end{itemize}
       \end{enumerate}
     \end{center}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to put the text into the center as shown on the screenshot below. I tried using a `center` environment, but that didn't produce the expected output. Then I tried using `vspace`, but I need to adjust again and again. Is there any package I can use for this?

[image]

Comment: So you still want the list to stack vertically (one element below the other)... you just want the entire list to be centered horizontally, right?

Comment: Yes, @Werner, I want the entire list to be centered horizontally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no easy way to automatically centre a list, since the degree of centring required will depend on the length of the longest line in the list.  However, it's not to difficult to set one value per frame that you need to do this on, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{12em}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
       \begin{enumerate}
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \begin{itemize}
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \item A1
        \end{itemize}
       \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you, but if there are some figures. Does the figure also  shift?

Comment: @ytyyutianyun I'm not sure what you mean. My example shows how you can  shift the left margin of the top level list inwards. Whatever content is in the items will also shift.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and what I mean is: In one frame, there is a figure and an item. I only want to shift the item, can I do this? thank you.

Comment: As long as the image isn't inside the list environment, it will be aligned on the left margin.