# Can I use Beamer's \alert<x>{...} inside fancyvrb Verbatim with overlay?

Tags: beamer, verbatim, overlays, fancyvrb

I would like to use Beamer's `\alert<x>{...}` command inside of a `Verbatim` environment (from the `fancyvrb` package) to highlight the text. I've found that when the `\alert` command is inside the `Verbatim`, it just highlights the text, but doesn't do any overlays.

> Can I use the overlay feature of `\alert` inside a `Verbatim` environment?

Note: I don't want to use a `semiverbatim` environment because I want to put a frame around the text. A minimal working example is copied below. It does not do what I'd like it to.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Testing}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\scriptsize,frame=single]
1.423930+0 8.164981+5 1.257190+02834 3  2  545
1.900300-1 \alert<2>{8.184120+5 3.506000-7}2834 3  2  546
2.307450-2 8.192910+5 2.396970-12834 3  2  547
\end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following may be a viable work-around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb

\let\oldalert\alert
\renewcommand{\alert}[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764
    \oldalert{#2}% Default overlay
  \else
    \oldalert<#1>{#2}% Specific overlay
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Testing}

Slide \alt<1>{1}{2}\ldots

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\scriptsize,frame=single]
1.423930+0 8.164981+5 1.257190+02834 3  2  545
1.900300-1 \alert[2]{8.184120+5 3.506000-7}2834 3  2  546
2.307450-2 8.192910+5 2.396970-12834 3  2  547
\end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `\alert` macro is first stored in `\oldalert` in order to preserve the overlay specification interface (requiring the use of `<`.`>`). Then it is redefined to capture an optional (overlay) and mandatory (stuff to alert) argument in a more traditional way. That is, the interface `\alert<.>{..}` is updated to reflect `\alert[.]{..}` which [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) seems to cope with better.

A simpler definition may be to only use

```
\let\oldalert\alert
\renewcommand{\alert}[2]{\oldalert<#1>{#2}}
```

which assumes you'll *always* specify an overlay and renews the interface to `\alert{.}{..}`.