# How to format subitems

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is 1
            \begin{enumerate}[a]
                \item This is a
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:
[image: output from beamer]

Note that the bullet for subitem `a` does not have proper format like `1`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _proper_ format? Do you want a dot after `a` as well? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No, I mean subitem style.

Comment: What, in your opinion, is proper subitem style?

Comment: @Mico That blue circle...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the `enumerate subitem` template:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[circle]%
\renewcommand{\insertsubenumlabel}{\alph{enumii}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is 1
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is a
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to me that `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[circle]` is not needed.