# How to change thanks symbol in beamer

Tags: beamer, symbols, footnotes

My code is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}



\begin{document}
\title[Title]{My title%
\thanks{\scriptsize Project supported by foundation: }} %<<----this place
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[\initclock\tdtime]{\today}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
  Some final text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the 1 to, for example, \aleph like below. How can I do this?
 thanks for advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}`?

Comment: Thanks, it works, you are good and helpful \(^o^)/YES！

Comment: Added as an answer... Remember that you can accept it, if it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply issue the command

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
```

If, for any reason, you want to turn back to numbers later in your document, you can restore the normal behavior with

```
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

and, if you want footnotes to restart from 1, add

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
```