# How to change background color of the frametitle (in warsaw theme)?

Tags: beamer, color

I'm using `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!cyan}` and it works for the top and bottom of the frame.

Now I want to change the background color of the frametitles. I've tried with `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=cyan}` but nothing happens. I want a plain color, not a gradient.

[image: This is a capture of a frame]

I get the following capture of the frame after applying Jesse's answer:

[image: ...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this answers your question where a possible solution comes from
[here](http://bloerg.net/2012/06/21/customizing-the-frametitle-of-beamer-presentation.html).  The `beamercolorbox` environment is used here and some [options] has to be set so that the title is centered.

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!cyan}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.8em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut
        \vskip-0.8ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
Blah blah
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should set the `frametitle right` template colour's `b`ack`g`round to `cyan!90`, or

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=cyan!90}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=cyan!90}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90}
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A section}
\end{frame}
\section{Another section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Another section}
\end{frame}
\section{Final section}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Final section}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is this cyan looking different than the "section title" cyan?

Comment: @yngve: This may stem from the fact that [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) uses palettes in its structure; shades of some primary specification with other colours.