# No cleveref in beamer?

Tags: beamer, cleveref, ntheorem

I am trying to get a math beamer presentation to work and it seems that `cleveref` is causing problems. The MWE below gives the error

```
Paragraph ended before \@ynthm was complete
```

In the documentation of `cleveref`, one finds the following remark:

> The `beamer` document class rededefines the `\label` command in a
>   particularly devious way that breaks `cleveref`'s optional argument to
>   that command.

What optional argument?  Does that mean that `cleveref` and `beamer` are simply incompatible? Is there any way around that problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\let\th@plain\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{MainThm}{Main Theorem}

\crefname{MainThm}{Main Theorem}{Main Theorems}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{MainThm}
        blabla
    \end{MainThm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do know that you shouldn't be using cross-references in a presentation in any case?

Comment: 1. Born to be wild. ;P
2. It is very useful to have that feature, if one can include LaTeX code from other documents like articles into the presentation without having to modify it.
3. It very useful to have that feature, if the document is supposed to be complied to multiple output formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) redefined `\label` to now take an optional argument that overrides the `cleveref` *type*. However, if you don't use this optional argument, then you're fine.

Switch the load order between `cleveref` and [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\makeatletter
\let\th@plain\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{MainThm}{Main Theorem}
\crefname{MainThm}{Main Theorem}{Main Theorems}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  See~\cref{thm:mytheorem}.
  \begin{MainThm}\label{thm:mytheorem}
    blabla
  \end{MainThm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```