# beamer with numbered theorems not working with cleveref

Tags: beamer, theorems, cleveref

A want to use cleveref in a beamer presentation. The document defines multiple theorem environments *sharing* the same counter as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{cor}
    foo bar
  \end{cor}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\endbeamercolorbox ->\ifdim \beamer@colbox@sep 
                                               =0pt\else \vskip \beamer@colb...
l.14 \end{frame}
```

Note that the example works fine if a separate counter for `cor` is used, i.e. if the 6th line is replaced by

```
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
```

I could not find any useful information about this. Any ideas how to get the original example working?

**Note:** This is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167422/no-cleveref-in-beamer). Cleveref *does* work together with beamer as long as separate counters are used. I could even add `\label` to the corollary and `\cref` it later and everything works fine.

However, if the two theorem environments use the same counter (as in my original example) the error occurs, even if no `\label` or `\cref` is used at all.

Comment: To would-be close-this-posting voters: The new question is *not* a duplicate of the earlier one. In particular, the remedy suggested there does not seem to work with the OP's stated setup.

Comment: Could someone please tell me why my question is considered a duplicate of that other question? Just because it contains "beamer", "cleveref" and "something does not work"?

To make it clear: I do *not* claim that cleveref does not work with beamer. In fact, it *does*. As long as I do not use a shared counter, everything works fine. I could even add a label to the `cor` and `cref` it later and the reference works correctly.

The problem is that the *shared* counter for the numbered theorems does not work with `cleveref` and causes the error even without using `\label` or `\cref` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not true that `cleveref` works with `beamer`; for instance, `\label` does not accept an optional argument.

Here's a hack that does what you're looking for. However, I don't think it's worthy the pain: your audience will not remember the theorem numbers, so referring to them by number will just be confusing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thmx}{\theoremname}
\newenvironment{thm}{\def\theoremname{Theorem}\thmx}{\endthmx}
\newenvironment{cor}{\def\theoremname{Corollary}\thmx}{\endthmx}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{cor}{Corollary}{Corollaries}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\beamer@label<#1>{%
    \def\hack@arg{#1}%
    \@ifnextchar[\beamer@label@opt\beamer@label@noopt
  }%
  \def\beamer@label@opt[#1]#2{%
    \expandafter\alt\expandafter<\hack@arg>%
      {\beamer@origlabel[#1]{#2}\beamer@nameslide{#2}}%
      {\beamer@dummynameslide}%
  }%
  \def\beamer@label@noopt#1{%
    \expandafter\alt\expandafter<\hack@arg>%
      {\beamer@origlabel{#1}\beamer@nameslide{#1}}%
      {\beamer@dummynameslide}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{cor}\label[cor]{A}
foo bar
\end{cor}

\cref{A}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it does not work for me in some cases but it should be good enough as a workaround.