# In beamer, how to temporarily cancel the frametitle

Tags: beamer, cancel

I have a image in this frame and I want to show it without any other item. Just like below.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
And my MWE is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
  picture
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `plain` option for the frame:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  picture
\end{frame}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  picture
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above, this, annihilates the decorative elements, but the width for the sidebar is still preserved, so you will need a negative `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \hspace*{-2.7cm}\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{ctanlion}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.</sub>

Comment: @ytyyutianyun You're welcome!

Comment: I need your help again. How can I cancel only the `navigation bar ` or `title`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to suppress? All of the `sidebar` (the blue stripe and its contents) or just the navigation part inside of it but keeping the blue stripe?

Comment: @ytyyutianyun perhaps you could consider opening a fresh new question as a follow-up to this one?

Comment: The blue stripe and its contents.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun this (although I acknowledge is related to the original question) demands a completely different approach, so I'd suggest you to open a fresh new question.

Comment: Ok, I submit [The second question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175956/how-can-i-cancel-only-the-navigation-bar-or-title-in-a-specified-frame)