# How can I cancel only the navigation bar or title in a specified frame

Tags: beamer, cancel

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Some more text
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
  picture
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The sidebar I means all the things including the blue stripe and its contents.

In [the related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167936/in-beamer-how-to-temporarily-cancel-the-frametitle), using `plain` is OK. However, this time I only want to cancel one thing, the navigation bar or title. How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution is a little more involved than the one suppressing both elements simultaneously with the `plain` option for `frame`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}

\let\Tiny\tiny

\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}

\makeatletter
\let\Oldbeamerleftsidebar\beamer@leftsidebar
\newcommand\RecoverSpace{%
  \parshape 1 \dimexpr\beamer@leftmargin-\Gm@lmargin\relax \dimexpr\linewidth-\beamer@leftmargin+\Gm@lmargin\relax
}
\newcommand\SuppressSidebar{%
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}
  \setlength\beamer@leftsidebar{0pt}%
}
\newcommand\SuppressTitle{%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
    \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
    \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
    \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
  }%
}
\newcommand\RecoverVSpace{%
  \vskip-\dimexpr\beamer@headheight+2.5ex\relax%
}
\makeatother

\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
A regular frame
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\SuppressSidebar
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
\RecoverSpace
Some text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text

\RecoverSpace
Some more text
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
Another regular frame
\end{frame}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begingroup
\SuppressTitle
\begin{frame}
\RecoverVSpace
Some text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text and some more text
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
\framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
Another regular frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks and explanation

Suppressing only the sidebar involves a number of actions:

1. Suppressing the information on the sidebar (the navigation bar).
2. Actually suppressing the sidebar
3. Regaining the space that was occupied by the sidebar.

Perhaps the more involved action is number three, since the extra spacing for the sidebar is globally set using `\setbeamersize` which can only be used in the preamble. I used some `\parshape` settings to define a `\RecoverSpace` command to regain the space; since `\parshape` only affects the current paragraph, `\RecoverSpace` will have to be applied to each paragraph in the modified frame.

For actions one and two I defined a `\SuppressSidebar` command.

In general, for frames in which you want to suppress the sidebar you will need to do this:

```
\begingroup
\SuppressSidebar
\begin{frame}
\RecoverSpace
contents
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

Suppressing only the title also involves a number of actions: setting the `headline` and `frametitle` templates to be empty, and recovering the vertical space assigned to the `headline` template. Those actions are done using the `\SuppressTitle` and `\RecoverVspace` commands.

In general, for frames in which you want to suppress the headline you will need to do this:

```
\begingroup
\SuppressTitle
\begin{frame}
\RecoverVSpace
contents
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

Comment: @ytyyutianyun You're welcome. In my updated answer I've added the code required to suppress only the headline.