# Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `******.out' has changed

Tags: errors, output

The warning continually appears and I always ignore it, but today I want to know how to deal with it.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=black!10}
\title[Title]{My title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{My institute}
\date[Date]{My date}
\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{\TeX}} % you can % it
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle}
  Some text
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

and the output is as followed:

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `model.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )<C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss12.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmss17.pfb><C:/CTEX/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb>
Output written on model.pdf (2 pages, 51454 bytes).
SyncTeX written on model.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on model.log.

gbk2uni, version 0.22, initially implemented by cxterm and ZLB in Jan. 2003
  enhanced by hooklee in Mar. 2003.
  please visit www.ctex.org and www.chinatex.org for more information.
gbk2uni model.out is finished!


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 2)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The warning says:

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `model.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
```

It is not clear to me, what is the question?

- `hyperref` creates the `.out` file for its bookmarks. It needs two passes. Thus rerun LaTeX.
- Or add `\usepackage{bookmark}`. Then a more modern implementation of the bookmarks managing is used without `.out` file. The bookmarks are updated earlier, thus in most cases only one LaTeX run is needed.

Comment: So you have no warning signals when you run the MWE? And I add `\usepackage{bookmark}` it works

Comment: @ytyyutianyun: Without package `bookmark` there is a warning in the *first* run and in each run, where the bookmarks are changed. In the second run of the MWE I do not have a warning.

Comment: Very thanks for solving my problem :-D

Comment: Without the `\usepackage{bookmark}`, I also get the warning in every run

Comment: @lucidbrot Sorry, I do not get your point. Package `bookmarks` fixes some problems because of its improved algorithm. That not using it does not fix these problems seems pretty clear, doesn't it? Please, make a new question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with a clear description, how it is compiled and about the error.

Comment: @Heiko The point of my comment was that the warning happens for me as well in every run. Even when recompiling three or four times. "Rerun to get outlines right" thus seems like useless advice in some cases like mine. I want to point out that it seems like only the second option (bookmark) helps.

Comment: @lucidbrot An advice that helps in more than 99.99% of the cases does not seem useless to me, especially it is the point of package `rerunfilecheck`. The other 0.01% needs investigation, that will not happen if there is nothing to investigate (MWE, versions, ...) and no volunteers that investigate.

Comment: @Heiko to be clear, i am not saying you should change your answer. All I want to do is tell other people that even if one approach does not work, the other is still worth trying