# How to left-align text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How to left-align text into the second `column`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{4.7cm}
\hspace{0.6cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{images/t}
\column{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7cm\relax}
\hspace*{-20pt}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth+20pt\relax}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item C.
\begin{itemize}
\item B.
\item A.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{columns}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to surround the content of the second column using this `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}`. But nothing has changed.

Thanks!

Comment: The text in the second column is a list. Do you want the items to be flush-left with the column boundary? Or do you want the list to be right next to the image, but still indented the way a list is supposed to be?

Comment: I want the list to be left next to the image, but still indented the way a list without changing the use of `columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\column` command (or `column` environment) takes a mandatory argument specifying the width of the column. You've specified `4.7cm`, yet the contents of the column is only `2.9cm` (plus some spurious space) wide. So you're left with `1.8cm` on the right of the image (at most). If you want the contents of the second column to be flush with the image, I'd suggest

1. making the first column less wide,
2. boxing the list content in the second column, and
3. moving the boxed list left using an `\hspace*`.

The above suggestions are incorporated in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{2.9cm}
      \hspace*{0.6cm}%
      \includegraphics[width=2.3cm,height=1.7cm]{example-image}%
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2.9cm\relax}
      \hspace*{-25pt}\parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \begin{itemize}
          \item C.
          \begin{itemize}
            \item B.
            \item A.
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      }
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```