# How to insert a picture without the name "figure"

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, captions

I am trying to put a figure with a subtitle but without the name "figure".

For example:

[image: triangle]

'This is a triangle'

and not put the name "Figure":

[image]

'Figure: This is a triangle'

I tried:

1.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=*]{fig.jpg}
\caption{*}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

2.

```
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[scale=*]{fig.jpg}
\caption{*}
\end{frame}
```

And neither have worked.

Comment: please indent your code examples with 4 spaces

Comment: Just don't use `\caption` and add the text as a normal paragraph.

Comment: it is not working...

Comment: @PoliTolstov: You need to include the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) in your preamble. Did you do that?

Comment: yes, it already has this package, but nothing has changed.

Comment: my document class is beamer... I am wondering if that is the problem!

Comment: @PoliTolstov I double checked. The suggested solution works with `beamer` as well, flawlessly. Are you sure that you really have the command `\usepackage{caption}` in preamble? You said that you "has this package", which is somewhat inconclusive, I must say.

Comment: The above discussion emphasises why we want you to supply a proper MWE, @PoliTolstov

Answer (score 11):

Use the `\caption*` command from [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig.jpg}
  \caption{This is a triangle.}
  \label{fig:tr1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig.jpg}
  \caption*{This is also a triangle.}
  \label{fig:tr2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Within a presentation (like [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)) there is very little need to have enumerated captions for images. Regardless, there is no need to always use a (floating) `figure` environment for including graphics, nor is it necessary to use `\caption` inside `figure`.

I would suggest merely using the `center` environment to center the object and add a piece of text below it to act like the caption:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  This is text.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}

    This is a rectangle
  \end{center}

  Here is some more text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to customise the `caption` itself. Like this you can keep your syntax.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        This is text.

        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{This is a rectangle}
        \end{figure}

        Here is some more text.
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]