# How to fix figure caption while using lmodern

Tags: captions, warnings, subcaption

To remove the warnings,

> Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available(Font) size <5>
>   substituted Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 1.0pt have
>   occurred.

I used the package `lmodern`, as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/how-to-remove-the-warnings-font-shape-ot1-cmss-m-n-in-size-4-not-available). However, it does create some problems in figure and sub-figure captions.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern, subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\subfigure[$A$-−$B$-−$C$-−$D$-−$A$-−$C$]{
}
\caption{$A$-−$B$-−$C$-−$D$-−$A$-−$C$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hae an unicode character at `-−`. The second one is an ndash.
This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfigure[$A$---$B$---$C$---$D$---$A$---$C$]{foo}
\caption{$A$---$B$---$C$---$D$---$A$---$C$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Alternetively define a new unicode char:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern, subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{−}{--}% First one is an n-dash not a hyphen!
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\subfigure[$A$-−$B$-−$C$-−$D$-−$A$-−$C$]{}
\caption{$A$-−$B$-−$C$-−$D$-−$A$-−$C$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for this MWE, but not for my original code. :-(

Comment: In your example the second `−` is not a hyphen, it is a n-dash which is in TeX notation `--`. Delete all those `-−` and replace them with `---`