# Beamer enumeration, continue counting but keep item at fixed position, II

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize, counters

I have a question similar to [Beamer enumeration, continue counting but keep item at fixed position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188034). But the solution provided by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188046 cannot make other counters on the second page work (e.g. step and be referenced).

I know I should comment directly under the question answer, but I can't because I don't have 50 reputation.

MWE

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\def\AdvCnt{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr\arabic{slideinframe}-1\relax}}
\pretocmd{\item}{\AdvCnt}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\only<+>{
  \item Item 1 \label{enu:1}
  \begin{equation}
  a+b=c\label{equ:1}
  \end{equation}
}
\only<+>{
  \item Item 2 \label{enu:2}
  \begin{equation}%\refstepcounter{equation}
  d+e=f\label{equ:2}
  \end{equation}
}
\end{enumerate}
\ref{enu:1}, \eqref{equ:1}, \ref{enu:2}, \eqref{equ:2}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `\label` macro will try to create a label on the first overlay. As some of your items/equations are not present on the first overlay, you get undefined references.

To avoid this, you can use `\label<>{...}` to link to a specific overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother
\def\AdvCnt{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr\arabic{slideinframe}-1\relax}\setcounter{equation}{\numexpr\arabic{slideinframe}-1\relax}}
\pretocmd{\item}{\AdvCnt}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\only<+>{
  \item Item 1 \label{enu:1}
  \begin{equation}
  a+b=c\label{equ:1}
  \end{equation}
}
\only<+>{
  \item Item 2 \label<.>{enu:2}
  \begin{equation}
  d+e=f\label<.>{equ:2}
  \end{equation}
}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{enu:1}, \eqref{equ:1}, \ref{enu:2}, \eqref{equ:2}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Imho, the approach you choose to display items one at a time is quite invasive and will alter the behaviour of all items in your presentation. I would suggest this less invasive approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}
\alt<1>{
  \item Item 1 \label{enu:1}
  \begin{equation}
  a+b=c\label{equ:1}
  \end{equation}
}{
  \refstepcounter{enumi}
  \refstepcounter{equation}
  \item Item 2 \label<2>{enu:2}
  \begin{equation}
  d+e=f\label<2>{equ:2}
  \end{equation}
}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{enu:1}, \eqref{equ:1}, \ref{enu:2}, \eqref{equ:2}.
\pause
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```