# How to align the image and algorithm in the frame?

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

The following is the code and its output. The output doesn't look well. If they are both aligned horizontally by their left and then centered in the frame, it will looks better. But how? (The image is centered in the frame.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=3cm]{fig4}

    \medskip

    %\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.66\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
    \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[s+1]$\;
    \everypar={\nl}
    \For{$d=0$ \KwTo $ptr[d+1]-ptr[d]$}{
      \For{$l=0$ \KwTo $ptr[d+1]-prt[d]$}{
        $z[l] \leftarrow z[l]+val[prt[d]+l] \cdot x[\textcolor{red}{ind[ptr[d]+l]}]$\;
      }
    }
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
   %}
  \end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want the image to be left-aligned just like the algorithm? It's not clear from your post.

Comment: @Werner: I am sorry and I have modified my question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set both items in a `minipage` of similar widths. Then adjustments to the horizontal alignment should match, since the `minipage` has a default left-alignment (actually justified):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=3cm]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}

  \medskip

  \begin{minipage}{.8\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \DontPrintSemicolon
      \KwSty{type} val : \KwSty{real}$[k]$\;
      \KwSty{type} ind : \KwSty{int}$[k]$\;
      \KwSty{type} ptr : \KwSty{int}$[s+1]$\;
      \everypar={\nl}
      \For{$d=0$ \KwTo $ptr[d+1]-ptr[d]$}{
        \For{$l=0$ \KwTo $ptr[d+1]-prt[d]$}{
          $z[l] \leftarrow z[l]+val[prt[d]+l] \cdot x[\textcolor{red}{ind[ptr[d]+l]}]$\;
        }
      }
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```