# Beamer : hyperlink to againframe

Tags: beamer, hyperref

How to make an hyperlink to jump to the first slide selected by `\againframe` ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

\begin{enumerate}[<+>]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3 %\hyperlink to the \againframe below
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2,4,6>{bob}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

\begin{enumerate}[<+>]

\item 1
\item 2
\item 3 \hyperlinkframestartnext{Animation}
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

% append page duration to the page attributes (do it manually)
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \pdfpageattr{
    \the\pdfpageattr /Dur 0.2
    /AA <<
      /O <<
        /S/JavaScript /JS(
          if(this.pageNum==this.numPages-1)
            var retVal=app.setTimeOut( "this.pageNum=6;", 200 );
        )
      >>
    >>
  }%
}%
\x

\againframe<2,4,6>{bob} %auto-advancing frames

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there are other frames between bob-frame and `againframe`. Doesn't matter now, but any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees that this won't break anything, but maybe you could temporarily redefine the `relabel` key to smuggle in a new label, let's call it `foo`, into the repeated frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

\begin{enumerate}[<+>]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3 \hyperlink{foo<4>}{link text}%\hyperlink to the \againframe below
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
other frame
\end{frame}

{
\makeatletter
  \define@key{beamerframe}{relabel}{\def\beamer@againname{foo}%
    {\let\@elt\beamer@labelsavecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
  }
\makeatother
\againframe<2,4,6>{bob}
}

\end{document}
```