# Beamer : hyperlink, invisible, non clickable when invisible but taking his room problem

Tags: beamer, overlays, links

I'd like to have an hyperlink non clickable when invisible but whith the taking his space like with `onslide` instead of `only` :

In this example :

- the item-2 is correct (invisible, non clickable when invisible)
- the item-3 is incorrect (invisible, but clickable when invisible)
- the item-4 is incorrect (invisible, non clickable when invisible) but doen't take his room.

How to fix this ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

bla

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]

\item 1
\item 3 \hyperlink<2>{bob<1>}{Back}
\item 3 \hyperlink{bob<1>}{Back}
\item 2 \hyperlink<4>{bob<1>}{Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla}
\end{enumerate}

bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd try `\only<4>{\hyperlink{bob<1>}{Bla Bla Bla ... Bla}}`

Comment: Doesn't take room on other slides than 4 ? I begin to understand that what I'm asking is not possible, I'll try to put the hyperlink on the itmize sign.

Comment: I think so. Quote from `beameruserguide.pdf`, p. 24:  "On non-specified slides the \only command simply “throws its argument away” and the argument does not occupy any space."

Comment: You also need to \usepackge{hyperref} to use \hyperlink and \hypertarget.  It's in the manual.

Comment: In beamer class manual 3.33 on page 17 it written that the hyperref package is automatically laoded by beamer.cls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own macro to achieve the intended output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764

\newcommand<>{\althyperlink}[2]{%
    \alt#3{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]

bla

\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item 1
\item 3 \althyperlink<2>{bob}{Back}
\item 3 \althyperlink{bob}{Back}
\item 2 \althyperlink<4>{bob}{Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla}
\end{enumerate}


bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```