# How to use \beamer@frametitle value as an argument to \settowidth

Tags: beamer, titles, lengths

I was customizing a `beamer` theme that have to be used by many people at my workplace. I want to show an error whenever frame-title takes more than two lines. Please don't ask why title is so long. So I thought that by defining a custom length and setting it to the width of frame-title, I can compare this custom length to a threshold value and show the error. However I am not able to set the width of my custom length to frame-title. The error I am getting is undefined control sequence. An MWE is as following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
    \newlength \myl
    \def \cm {\beamer@frametitle}
    \settowidth{\myl}{\cm}  %error ! Undefined control sequence.
    %\settowidth{\myl}{Example frame} %68.2551pt
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Example frame}
        \the \myl  
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am new to custom themes. So If anyone can help me for if construct of lengths with a greater than comparison. It will be grate for me. I already tried using `\if` and `\ifx` available on wikibooks which both did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example patches the `\frametitle` command to update the length `\titlelen` that gives the length of the title under the current theme's font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\titlelen}
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\beamer@@frametitle}% <cmd>
  {\gdef\beamer@frametitle}% <search>
  {\settowidth{\titlelen}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}#2}%
   % ...condition here, if necessary...
   \gdef\beamer@frametitle}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example frame}

  {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}Example frame}

  \rule{\titlelen}{1pt}

  \the\titlelen

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

While some action can be taken at the step indicated above, the changed macro - `\beamer@@frametitle` - constructs the frame title setting not just via `\beamer@frametitle`, but also `\insertframetitle`. So, if you wish to change the frame title to (say) "Too long" if the users inputs (say) "This is a super long frame title that is actually too long", then the following setup might work better:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\makeatletter
\newlength{\titlelen}
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \settowidth{\titlelen}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}#2}%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \ifdim\the\titlelen>300pt\relax
      \gdef\beamer@frametitle{Too long}%
    \else
      \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
    \fi
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{\beamer@frametitle\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}%
    \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{This is a super long frame title that is actually too long}

  {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}Example frame}

  \rule{\titlelen}{1pt}

  \the\titlelen

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner for your answer. It is the thing I was looking for. I used '\ifdim \titlelen>300pt \gdef\beamer@frametitle} {Too long}{}' but it is giving error. Can you redirect me to correct construct.

Comment: @VirendraSingh: See the updated answer...

Answer (score 5):

First, why not just use `\insertframetitle`? Second, I don't think `\beamer@frametitle` is defined outside of a frame. That's why you probably get the error message. Third, you should also consider the font (shape, size, ...) in your calculations. Have a look at this example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength\myframetitlelength

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Example frame}
        \insertframetitle
        \settowidth{\myframetitlelength}{\insertframetitle}
        \the\myframetitlelength

        Example frame%
        \settowidth{\myframetitlelength}{Example frame}
        \the\myframetitlelength

        {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle}
        \settowidth{\myframetitlelength}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle}
        \the\myframetitlelength
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**
[image: beamer_frametitle]

---

This example demonstrates why using `\insertframetitle` makes sense here. The threshold (100pt) is set just between the two widths of the first and second frame. You should obviously change it to a higher value.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\myframetitlelength

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \settowidth{\myframetitlelength}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle}%
  \ifdim\myframetitlelength>100pt%
    \PackageWarning{}{Frametitle is too long: \the\myframetitlelength.}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Example frame}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your question I will say that in the definition of \insertframetitle there is some complicated code whereas I found \beamer@frametitle more clear. Being new to these things I prefer clearer code. Well thanks for your answer.

Comment: The "complicated code" you are talking about is to support frame breaks (`allowframebreaks` option). So thinking about it again, `\beamer@frametitle` and also Werners solution will result in a wrong width in these cases. So you really should use `\insertframetitle`.

Comment: Actually the font settings are internal and same for everyone.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to demonstrate why you should use `\insertframetitle`.