# Combine Warsaw and Boadilla

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates

I am using `beamer` to make a presentation.

I like the `Warsaw` theme, but I also like `Boadilla` navigation bar.
So my idea is using `Warsaw` theme, but at bottom of each slide I want it to be shown like `Boadilla`: 40% dedicated to my name and institute, 40% to the topic name and 20% to the page number (Page #).

Comment: Yes use beamer to make a presentation. I do not know how to insert a picture. but my idea is to have a slide with warsaw theme, but the bottom bar should have 3 slices instead of 2.  First slice is about my name and institute, 4/10 total bar space. second slice is about my topic, also 4/10 tatal bar space. and last is for page number, 2/10 bar space.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Warsaw` theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeWarsaw.sty) of [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) uses the [`shadow` outer theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemeshadow.sty) which, in turn, is based on the [`split` outer theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemesplit.sty). The `split` outer theme sets the footline using the following template construction:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

From the above it's clear that `split`'s `footline` template creates the 50%-50% view you mention under `Warsaw`. Let's update this to suit your needs, now creating a 40%-40%-20% layout:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\usecolortheme{dolphin}% from Boadilla

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertnameinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\inserttopic
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}Page~\insertframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
  }
\newcommand{\insertnameinstitute}{\insertshortauthor, \insertshortinstitute}
\newcommand{\topic}[1]{\def\currenttopic{#1}}\topic{}
\newcommand{\inserttopic}{\currenttopic}

\author[A Author]{An Author}
\institute[Institute]{INSTITUTE}
\title[A title]{An interesting title}

\topic{Some topic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{foo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am unfamiliar with your choice of the term topic, as there's no such definition in `beamer` that I know of. Instead, I created `\topic{<topic>}` that you can change on the fly throughout the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}%  from Boadilla
\useoutertheme{infolines}% from Boadilla
\begin{document}
    \frame{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want navigation bar at upper slide. Also for the bottom navigation I don't want it be evenly distributed. 4/10, 4/10 and 2/10(without time).