# labels beside to figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, positioning

I tried to put labels beside the second figure, its not a subfigure. In the document i used the command `\topinset` but in `beamer` I can't use this.

I am currently creating a third new small column width, but does not give good results, like this.

```
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Estado estacionario del convertidor H-NPC}
\vspace{-1.2cm}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\[\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figs_ch4/ig.eps}\]
\caption{ \justifying .}
\end{figure}
\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\[\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figs_ch4/todos2.eps}\]
\caption{ \justifying .}
\end{figure}

\column{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{scriptsize}
\vspace{-85pt}
a)
b)
\vspace{40pt}
c)
\end{scriptsize}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, make your code sniped compilable!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The width of the collection of `\column`s is too wide: `0.5\textwidth` + `0.5\textwidth` + `0.05\textwidth` > `\textwidth`. Go with something less wide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
  \frametitle{A frame title}

  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.4\textwidth}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-a} \\
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-b} \\
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Left figure}
    \end{figure}

    \column{0.4\textwidth}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-a} \\
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-b} \\
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=20pt]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Right figure}
    \end{figure}

    \column{0.1\textwidth}
      \rule{0pt}{20pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr10pt+0.5\height}{\small a)} \\
      \rule{0pt}{20pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr10pt+0.5\height}{\small b)} \\
      \rule{0pt}{20pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr10pt+0.5\height}{\small c)}
  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}‎
```