# Beamer: keep text position in consecutive frames (or how to get overprint to increment frame number)

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to have a text with fixed position across two consecutive frames. When I try overprint, it works, but the frame number stays the same for the two frames. How can I have it incremented on the second frame?

Example of what I have:

```
\begin{frame}
Common text, that keeps its position in the two frames \\

\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
  First slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\

\onslide<2>
  Second slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
  Some more text

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
```

The first slide shows "**Frame - 6 of 10**" and the second one also shows "**Frame - 6 of 10**". I want it to show "**Frame - 7 of 11**".
Is there a way I can manually increase the counters? Or is there a better way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could show the page number instead of the frame number. However, this would increment with every overlay.

Comment: Quick hack: `\only<2>{\addtocounter{framenumber}{1}}`, but in the long run, it seems you don't want the framenumber to be shown, but the pagenumber.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with page number is that it would increment every time I use \pause. I just found a good solution for my specific case by using vbox. I posted the code as an answer. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got a solution with *vbox*:

```
\begin{frame} %1
\vbox to 0.13\textheight{%
 Common text \\
 }

\vbox to 0.45\textheight{%
  First slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame} %2
\vbox to 0.13\textheight{%
 Common text \\
 }

\vbox to 0.45\textheight{%
  Second slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
  Some more text
}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can trick beamer into increasing the framenumber in between the overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Common text, that keeps its position in the two frames \\

\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
  First slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\

\only<2>{\addtocounter{framenumber}{1}}

\onslide<2>
  Second slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
  Some more text

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Technically you're on the same `frame`, but a different *slide*. For this you should either separate the content on different `frame`s making space or using boxes/`\phantom`s to replicate the `overprint` area:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Common text, that keeps its position in the two frames

First slide \\
Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
\phantom{Some more text}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Common text, that keeps its position in the two frames

Second slide \\
Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
Some more text

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or, you can step the counter manually within the same `frame`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Common text, that keeps its position in the two frames

\begin{overprint}

\onslide<1>
  First slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\

\only<2>{\stepcounter{framenumber}}

\onslide<2>
  Second slide \\
  Frame - \insertframenumber{} of \inserttotalframenumber \\
  Some more text

\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```