# How does beamer's \lecture command influence the title?

Tags: beamer, titles

Given the following:

```
\lecture{Shortname}{Longname}{Label}

\begin(frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

How does beamer infer to insert the first argument of `\lecture` to be the title used in `\titlepage`?

I've searched my texlive installation (texlive-beamer-svn36461.3.36-24.fc24.1.noarch) but couldn't find where or how `\beamer@shortlecturename` is turned into `\inserttitle`?

What I would like to accomplish is that `Longname` is used in `\titlpage` instead of `Shortname`.

**Update**:

Turns out `\lecture` is not the culprit here. An MWE of what I'm actually doing looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\titlestring}{Title}

\title{\titlestring}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\renewcommand{\titlestring}{Topic}

\lecture[\titlestring]{\titlestring, YYYY-MM-DD}{Label}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I still don't get is why `\titlpage` picks up the changed `\titlestring`.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your current setup. Not only are you using incorrect notation - `\lecture[<short>]{<long>}{<label>}` - but the default [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) theme doesn't include `<shortname>` as part of the `\titlepage`.

Comment: @Werner, you're right. I've added an MWE to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

`\titlepage` picks up the changed `\titlestring` because you changed `\titlestring`; it's as simple as that. If you wish `\titlepage` to instead use `\titlestring, YYYY-MM-DD`, you can update `\inserttitle` manually using

```
\renewcommand{\inserttitle}{\titlestring, YYYY-MM-DD}
```

Here is a complete minimal example showing the redefinition of `\title`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\newcommand{\titlestring}{Title}

\title{\strut\titlestring}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\renewcommand{\titlestring}{Topic}

\lecture[\titlestring]{\titlestring, YYYY-MM-DD}{Label}

\title{\strut\titlestring, YYYY-MM-DD}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `\strut`s adde to the `\title` ensure a consistent baseline and avoids jumping between the frames/pages (may be specific to your example, as it won't be noticeable if the `\titlepage`s are consecutive.