# Warning Font shape `T1/cmss/m/n' in size not available when using \mathsf{c}

Tags: fontsize

I'm writing a document with a book structure using only these few packages:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondox,scr=boondox,bb=boondox,frak=euler]{mathalfa}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

I decided to define a personal command to denote the complement of a set as follows:

```
\newcommand{\comp}{\mathsf{c}}
```

And I intend to use it as `$A^\comp$` or `\[ A^\comp \]`, only in math environments. Although the document compiles and I have no problems with the output, a warning appears in the Log:

```
Font shape `T1/cmss/m/n' in size <5.5> not available(Font) size <5> substituted
```

How can I fix this warning? In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/how-to-remove-the-warnings-font-shape-ot1-cmss-m-n-in-size-4-not-available) it is suggested to add `\usepackage{lmodern}`. I did it, but the whole font was modified and I hated it. I changed `\mathsf{c}` to `c`, just to try, and indeed the warning is no more, so the problem comes from using `\mathsf`.

Any help will be appreciated. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[xcharter]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondox,scr=boondox,bb=boondox,frak=euler]{mathalfa}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand{\comp}{\mathsf{c}}

\begin{document}
$A^\comp$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just ignore it. It is just warning you it's made a font substitution. So long as you're happy about the substitution, there's no problem.

Comment: Those type of warnings should be a different category class really. If it can be ignored, so what. But other warnings completely rip your tex appart, not so so what...