# On the saturation of fontsize

Tags: fontsize, grids, fbox

Below I wrote a code using the grid package showing:

1. When the fontsize is 20 the height of the parenthesis is 20 points, which is what we expect.
2. When the fontsize is 40 the height of the parenthesis is around 35 points, less than what we expect.
3. When the fontsize is 60 the height of the parenthesis is around 35 points, much less than we expect.

So I observe a fontsize saturation meaning the actual font size remains unchanged after we put fontsize greater than 40 points. Is this a valid observation? If yes, how we make fontsize as large as 60 points?

```
\documentclass{book}

\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{red}{white}}

\usepackage[grid,
 gridcolor=blue!60!white,
 subgridcolor=green!40!white,
 gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\myfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{20}{20} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\bigfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{40}{40} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\biggerfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{60}{60} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
\myfont \fbox{(}\fbox{a}

\bigfont \fbox{(}\fbox{a}

\biggerfont \fbox{(}\fbox{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should look at the font warnings in your `.log`. Substitutions are made for the `40pt` and `60pt` requests, defaulting to `35.83pt`. That's why you see the same output in both for `(a`. Add `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` to your preamble to see the difference.

Comment: @Werner It is my 1st time to search for a log file. Do you know how the get my .log file? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are you using Overleaf? If so, see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files. You might want to view the "Raw logs".

Comment: The reason I did not see my log file was I used PDFLATEX+MAKEINDEX+BIBTEX. Now I only use PdfLaTeX and I see the log file generated. Thanks!

Comment: @Werner Would you please put your answer below then I accept it as a correct answer?

Comment: Also see [How to remove the warnings “Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available” and “Size substitutions with differences” in `beamer`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the font warnings in your `.log` (often hidden from view when using Overleaf). Substitutions are made for the `40pt` and `60pt` (as well as the `20pt`) requests, defaulting to `35.83pt`:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size  not available
(Font)              size  substituted on input line 17.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size  not available
(Font)              size  substituted on input line 19.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size  not available
(Font)              size  substituted on input line 21.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size  not available
(Font)              size  substituted on input line 23.
```

That's why you see the same output in both for `(a` associated with the `40pt` and `60pt` font sizes. Add `\usepackage{anyfontsize}` to your preamble to see the difference where fonts are scaled as necessary if they aren't available.