# Different column widths using multicol

Tags: multicol, width, flowfram

Is it possible to specify different column widths in a `multicol` environment? For example, in a two column layout, can the left column be set to twice the width of the right column?

Comment: No, as in most TeX column/page breaking the text is _first_ set into an (essentially) infinite scroll and only later that scroll is chopped in to columns of the right length, there is no feedback from the column/page splitting to the line breaking.

Comment: if you do not need a pagebreak than you can use a `tabularx`.

Comment: Possibly the `flowfram` package is what you're looking for.

Comment: If all else fails, I can add this as an option to the `pullquote` package ;-)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For a **single page**  the package `vwcol` (vari­able-width mul­ti­ple text columns) make  is what you're looking for.

```
 \documentclass{article} 
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{vwcol}  
 \begin{document} 
 \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.6,0.4},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em] 
 \lipsum[1-8] 
 \end{vwcol} 
 \end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]

For **multiple pages** the suggested `flowfram` package can help, but mostly with columns (frames) of different heights and places but the same width. Unfortunately the width of a paragraph cannot be changed when jump to a column of different width (the change in `\hsize` will not come into effect until the end of the paragraph), so it must be simulate a paragraph break with `\framebreak` or specified the exact point where the text paragraphs jump to the next column (with `\newpage` or `pagebrak[4]` or `\finishthispage` in the last column).

In the next example, the capture show when the  first `\newpage` is commented to explain the problem (otherwise the output is roughly similar to the first example, but the columns are not balanced in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newflowframe[1-5]
{0.60\textwidth}{\textheight}
{0pt}{0pt}[leftcolumn]

\newflowframe[1-5]{0.30\textwidth}{\textheight}
{0.65\textwidth}{0pt}[rightcolumn]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage 
\lipsum[6-8]
\newpage
\lipsum[9-12]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

**Edit**:

Another option is `paracol`. It can make columns of different widths using `\columnratio` in multiple pages, but switch of the column is always your work. This mean that if the text reach the end of some column, continues in the next page in the same column, not in the next right column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,parskip,color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\columnratio{0.6}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1] \switchcolumn \color{red} 
\lipsum[3] \switchcolumn \color{blue}
\lipsum[4] \switchcolumn \color{green}
\lipsum[5] \switchcolumn \color{green}
\lipsum[6] \switchcolumn \color{magenta} % flow to the next page
\lipsum[7] \switchcolumn \color{black} % flow to the next page
\lipsum[8] 
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the `vwcol` environment working with Beamer documents?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa It work, but the `beamer` class  provide  the [`columns` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32931/multiple-columns-with-images-and-wrapped-text-in-beamer), so I do not see the benefit of use `wvcol` in presentations.

Comment: I tried again `wvcol` and it is ignored by the compiler. But the `columns` environment works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Does `vwcol` support absolute width assignment(e.g. 4cm, 5cm for two columns)?

Comment: How can I tell `vwcol` where to break the columns?

Comment: @RobertP., use `\vfill\eject`.

Comment: @Fran, It is not working while giving ``Verbatim`` inside.

Comment: Why not use tcolorbox sidebyside