# Make two columns one greater in size than the other

Tags: multicol

I want to have the right two columns out of three merged together in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
Stuff
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Or maybe make two columns but one of them takes two thirds of the page.

Any ideas how to do this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Different column widths using multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: This is a quite frequent question, if you google for "multicols" and "width". The packages flowfram and vwcol and the answers I'm reading all are of the pre LuaTeX age. I wonder if someone might write a lua package e.g. solving the issue.

Comment: is it for a single page or multi page

Comment: @jsbibra Single page