# How I increase the space of weight in only one column?

Tags: multicolumn

I wanna for example, the text of left filling more space than the text from right column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
 \section{First Section}
  All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs      must obey.
 ]
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.
If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have the left column 2/3 of the total textwidth and the right only 1/3? That's been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/different-column-widths-using-multicol).