# Square table on the right column

Tags: tables, layout

I have a latex code here :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\newlist{todolist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[todolist]{label=$\square$}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Immediate plan of action.

  \begin{todolist}
    \item List item 1 goes here.
    \item List item 2 goes here.
    \begin{todolist}
      \item Sublist item 1 goes here.
      \item Sublist item 2 goes here.
    \end{todolist}
    \item List item 3 goes here
    \item List item 4 goes here.
  \end{todolist}

\end{itemize}

\columnbreak



\begin{TAB}(r,1cm,1cm)[5pt]{|cccccccccc|}{|cccccccccc|}
A & I & I & R & D & A & T & O & Y & T \\ 
C & O & M & M & U & T & A & T & O & R \\ 
P & S & Y & A & I & C & R & G & B & S \\ 
D & R & Q & U & O & T & I & E & N & T \\ 
E & O & A & A & B & E & L & I & A & N \\ 
M & I & D & C & O & A & P & A & A & H \\ 
I & T & U & P & R & O & D & U & C & T \\ 
M & O & N & G & W & A & R & T & T & T \\ 
R & T & T & A & P & I & T & O & A & T \\ 
S & E & M & I & G & R & O & U & P & C \\ 
\end{TAB}

\end{multicols}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{itemize}
  \item 1.

  \begin{todolist}
    \item List item 1 goes here.
    \item List item 2 goes here.
    \begin{todolist}
      \item Sublist item 1 goes here.
      \item Sublist item 2 goes here.
    \end{todolist}
    \item List item 3 goes here
    \item List item 4 goes here.
  \end{todolist}

\end{itemize}

\columnbreak


\begin{TAB}(r,1cm,1cm)[5pt]{|cccccccccc|}{|cccccccccc|}
A & I & I & R & D & A & T & O & Y & T \\ 
C & O & M & M & U & T & A & T & O & R \\ 
P & S & Y & A & I & C & R & G & B & S \\ 
D & R & Q & U & O & T & I & E & N & T \\ 
E & O & A & A & B & E & L & I & A & N \\ 
M & I & D & C & O & A & P & A & A & H \\ 
I & T & U & P & R & O & D & U & C & T \\ 
M & O & N & G & W & A & R & T & T & T \\ 
R & T & T & A & P & I & T & O & A & T \\ 
S & E & M & I & G & R & O & U & P & C \\ 
\end{TAB}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The column on the right does not seem to be a square.
How can I make it to a square with a specific font size.
How can I reduce the margin of the page?

How can I reduce the width of first column to give more space to second column?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `b` option in the `TAB` environment, which produces "equal row heights and equal column widths" (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easy/doc/doctable.pdf)). This results in a more square representation of the table. You may also consider using a monospaced font (like `\ttfamily`).

For margin adjustments, consider using [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry), either setting margins at package load (via the optional argument), or via `\geometry{...}`. Margins can be set individually (`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`), in pairs (`hmargin`, `vmargin`) or as a whole (`margin`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1]

\columnbreak

\begin{TAB}(b)[5pt]{|cccccccccc|}{|cccccccccc|}
  A & I & I & R & D & A & T & O & Y & T \\
  C & O & M & M & U & T & A & T & O & R \\
  P & S & Y & A & I & C & R & G & B & S \\
  D & R & Q & U & O & T & I & E & N & T \\
  E & O & A & A & B & E & L & I & A & N \\
  M & I & D & C & O & A & P & A & A & H \\
  I & T & U & P & R & O & D & U & C & T \\
  M & O & N & G & W & A & R & T & T & T \\
  R & T & T & A & P & I & T & O & A & T \\
  S & E & M & I & G & R & O & U & P & C
\end{TAB}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Added one more subquestion : How can I reduce the width of first column to give more space to second column?

Comment: @Vinod: For variable-width columns, see [Different column widths using `multicol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721/5764).

Answer (score 0):

The margin of the page can be reduced with the geometry package.  An example is below:

\usepackage[letterpaper,inner=1in,outer=.75in,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and make a small, but compilable test document instead of just a code fragment.